# Run a script when Windows resumes from suspend/hibernate state?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, script

Is there a way to have Windows (XP, Vista and 7) run a script when a machine returns from hibernate/suspend mode? It would be okay with me if the script runs after the user unlocks a locked session after their machine resumes.

I have a service that needs to be kicked when I a machine resumes in order to get it to run properly on resume.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In windows 7, you can do this with a scheduled task. Setup a batch script to do the actions you want and then create a task with one of the following triggers:

- On workstation unlock - Ignores first log on, but will start after unlock.
- On connection to user session - Every log on, can be local or remote connection.
- On an event - In the system log, the "Power-Troubleshooter" Source will log an event code of 1 when you wake up from a sleep state.

I have not tested these to make sure that they work as expected, but I have used "On workstation lock" with high amount of success. From what I remember of scheduled tasks in XP, it only has "When I log on".

[win 7 source doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx)

[win XP source doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that "On workstation lock/unlock" trigger options are only shown for "Create Task..." and not "Create Basic Task..."

Comment: The  "Power-Troubleshooter" source works also with Win 8.1.

Comment: The Power-Troubleshooter doesn't work for me in win 10 pro. The workstation unlock works anyway

Comment: "On workstation unlock" works for me

Comment: Event code 107 works for me in win 10 pro

Answer (score 2):

Using [Win32_PowerManagementEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394362.aspx)? I just googled it and found the [following script](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/running-scripts-standby-t434504.html) (no warranty;).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
ExecNotificationQuery("Select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent")

Do
  Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent

  Select Case objLatestEvent.EventType

    Case 4
      oShell.Run "Calc.exe", 1, False
      MsgBox "Entering suspend, Calc started", _
      vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "Suspend"

    Case 7
      oShell.Run "Notepad.exe", 1, False
      MsgBox "Resuming from suspend, notepad started", _
      vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "Suspend"

    Case 11
      MsgBox "OEM Event happened, OEMEventCode = " _
      & strLatestEvent.OEMEventCode

    Case 18
      MsgBox "Resume Automatic happened"

  End Select
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a scheduled task with trigger: on workstation unlock.
It works, I run it after wake up from sleep. 
Om my Windows 2008R2 box the audio service needs to be restarted, otherwise sometimes it uses 100% of 1 cpu.

Answer (score -1):

I actually did write such a script a while ago and [blogged](http://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/run-a-script-when-the-machine-comes-out-of-suspendsleep-via-wmi-event-consumer/) about it, but I do believe it was a bit after your question here. Next time I write something like this I will search Stack  Overflow right away, because when people look for such things, they tend to go to this site nowadays.

Comment: While having a link is nice, could you maybe post the important parts (even the script) here, on-site? This way users won't have to go somewhere else, and in case the blog ever goes down we have a backup.