# Disabled Touchscreen of Lenovo X220 (tablet) re-enable after ever sleep and wake in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, thinkpad, touchscreen, device-manager

I disabled the Touchscreen of my Lenovo X220 (core i7) tablet due to over-sensitivity (it registers some non-existing 'touches' itself) in the Device Manager according to this previous post:

[How do I disable the touch screen on Windows 8.1 for a Lenovo X220?](https://superuser.com/questions/692250/how-do-i-disable-the-touch-screen-on-windows-8-1-for-a-lenovo-x220)

It works right after I have disabled it. However, as soon as it has entered a sleep mode or a hibernation mode or has been rebooted, then the touchscreen is automatically enabled again. It wasn't like this before, and now it is quite annoying because my X220 is set to sleep with a 5-10 minutes idle time.

Has anyone experienced this? Or is it just some kind of Lenovo driver update / plug-and-play issue?

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I am running Windows 10 x64 with all the latest windows updates and Lenovo updates.

Comment: run devcon to disable the device when windows resumes again. this can be done by attaching a command to the event that gets raised when windows resumes.

Comment: What do you mean by "devcon"? Is that a Windows command in windows paths?

Comment: So I have to install DevCon in Windows 10 first. (http://keepthetech.com/2016/07/install-devcon-tool-in-windows-10.html) My question is also that why this (the device automatically re-enabled) was not the case a few months ago / before some Windows updates.

Comment: ms released several updates, so one of them broke this. use event 1 of  "Power-Troubleshooter" Source and run the command here http://superuser.com/a/276095/174557

Comment: So I tried to find out how to install DevCon and I am quite surprised that I need 12+ Gb disk space just to have a command line tool that helps me to re-disable a device driver every time when my laptop wakes up. Reason to need 12+ Gb space is that DevCon (Devcon.exe) is included when you [install the WDK, Visual Studio, and the Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) for desktop apps. And the first step, when I chose the smallest express version is [already 12+ Gb](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit) ...

Comment: Is there a more reasonable way to acquire just the Devcon.exe ?

Comment: I found a [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe) leading to ways to extract and install only the DevCon.exe, also including a suggestion for Windows 10 x64.

Comment: I created as a scheduled task with elevated privilege (Administrator, logged on or not, run with highest privileges) that triggers based on 1. logging on, 2. starting up, 3. unlocking i.e. security / event 4801, 4. waking up i.e. power troubleshooter / event 1, to run DevCon to disable my touchscreen. The command works to disable the touch screen device in elevated command prompt, and a bat script that run the command also works when run as admin. However, the scheduled task doesn't work while run on demand work. Log shows it ran successfully. The touchscreen's probably enabled after the task.

Comment: make sure you select the option to run the task at highest Privileges in task scheduler.

Comment: I did. But it still doesn't work, because the re-enabling of devices probably happens AFTER the waking up and unlocking plus the running of the newly created DevCon scheduled task -- because I keep the Device Manager opened and the Touch Screen device is re-enabled right in front of me with a few flickers AFTER I have already unlocked to the Desktop.

Comment: look if there are events for enabling devices and add a task to this event